# Responsive inline-block not shrinking in Mozilla (alternate CSS method?)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to display a responsive (resizes with browser as it shrinks but maxes out at it's own maximum pixels) with a caption. I thought I had come up with a solution using

```
display:inline-block
```

on the parent div to the caption but then realized it does not work in Mozilla.

Here is my working solution (is not responsive in Mozilla - image never shrinks):
http://jsfiddle.net/eBy9H/2/

Here is it without "inline block" and not displaying properly (when browser is wider than image the caption div "cappic" runs 100% of the parent div:
http://jsfiddle.net/eBy9H/1/

Is there a way to "shrink wrap: the caption div inside of it's parent so that it doesn't overflow without using inline-block (since it appears inline-block is not responsive in Mozilla)? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `max-width: 100%` on `.picwrap`. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBy9H/5/).

Comment: thank you so much, I was trying everything! strange that only Mozilla requires that extra declaration.

Comment: @OperAtor Once you have worked with browsers for a while, you realize that they are a _very_ flaky bunch. They don't play well in the school yard. They don't want to learn, they just make up their own (incorrect) knowledge. Blame their parents (the browser devs).